# Adding scale bar to raster overlayed on ggmap Google Maps object

Tags: raster, legend, ggmap

I am trying to plot a predicted surface (raster layer) over a `ggmap` object that contains base imagery from Google Earth. I have produced the map that I want however, I am struggling to add the legend scalebar.

To add the raster over top the `ggmap` object, I used the `inset_raster` function and I am not sure where to map the aesthetics to produce the proper legend based on the color scale I assigned the raster.

Below is an example of my code. Does anyone have advice on how to add the legend based on the `inset_raster` object?

```
rsfmap <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = c(lon = x, lat = y), 
                              zoom = 9, 
                              maptype = "hybrid"),
                              extent = "device", darken = 0.05, legend='right')

rsfmap+
  geom_point(aes(x=coords.x1, y=coords.x2), size=1, alpha=0.75, data=mydata) +
  inset_raster(as.raster(ggras, col=(topo.colors(500, alpha=0.4))), xmin = 
               ggras@extent[1], xmax = ggras@extent[2],ymin = ggras@extent[3], 
               ymax =  ggras@extent[4], interpolate = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out after finding this link: https://datacarpentry.org/r-raster-vector-geospatial/02-raster-plot/

Instead of using the inset_raster function. I transformed my raster into a dataframe and used the geom_raster function to add it to my ggmap, which has a more straight-forward mapping to the legend. Next, I used coord_fixed instead of coord_cartesian and set my ratio = 1.5 to improve the default appearance used with just coord_fixed. Really happy with the finished product. Hope someone finds this helpful!

```
myras <- projectRaster(my_prediction, 
            crs = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")) # convert to ggmap projection

myras <- as.data.frame(myras, xy=T, na.rm=T)

rsfmap <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = c(lon = x, lat = y), 
                              zoom = 9, 
                              maptype = "hybrid"),
                              extent = "device", darken = 0.05, legend='bottomleft')

rsfmap+
  geom_point(aes(x=coords.x1, y=coords.x2), size=2, alpha=1, shape=15, color='black', show.legend = T, data=mydata) +

  geom_raster(data = myras, aes(x = x, y = y, fill=layer)) +

  coord_fixed(ratio=1.5) +

  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=topo.colors(500, alpha=0.4), name="Nest\nProbability") +

  theme(legend.background=element_rect(fill=alpha('white', 0.4)),
        legend.text = element_text(size=12))`
```